# I want to check if brackets are in correct place or not but my code is not executing correctly

Tags: c++

here is my code it is working fine now but not giving the desire output 
ex for eq {a+(b-c)*d} the output should be 
"bracket matched popping ) 
bracket matched popping }"

but output is

"bracket dose not matched"

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main() {    
    string exp;
    cin >> exp;
//  cin.getline(exp);
    stack <char> s;
    for(int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '[') {
            s.push(exp[i]);
            continue;
        } else if(exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == ']') {
            if(s.top() == exp[i]) {
                cout << "bracket matched popping " << s.top() << endl;
                s.pop();
                continue;
            } else {
                cout << "bracket dose not matched" << endl;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Secondly, please edit your question to include a comment on the line you're getting the error (and also to include the *full* and *complete* copy-pasted error output).

Comment: Also you don't need those `continue` statements, the loop will continue anyway. Also don't loop until the null terminator, a `std::string` might have it embedded anywhere (and old versions of the C++ standard didn't require it). Either loop over the length, use iterators of [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: If you want help with a compiler error you really need to say which line has the error.

Comment: and your code do not check the missing ])} at the end

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude I have numeric 1 at the end of the code but I want to check that the brackets are in right position or not in a given equation but where i am getting wrong any help is appreciated

Comment: I got what was wrong in my code after dry run thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong, C++ strings are not null terminated

```
for(int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

Do this

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++) {
```

Comment: They're guaranteed to have `\0` at the end since at least C++11, aren't they?. Such loop condition would give incorrect results if you have `\0` in the middle of your string, yes; but that's not what happens in OP's case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Good to know, yet another case of my C++ being out of date. Would still prefer to see my version of the loop though.

Comment: I have done this and now changed my code also but now also it is changing my output

Answer (score 4):

because ( is not ) not [ is not ] nor { is not }

when you read a ( you have to push a ) rather than a ( etc, or you have to change the test `(s.top() == exp[i])`

Comment: So obvious! Yet so easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison for the parenthesis match is wrong:

```
  if(s.top() == exp[i]) {
```

That would mean that you expect '(' to close '('.

You need to expand that comparison to the respective expected opening parenthesis - i.e., if you currently encounter ']', you need to check for '[' on the stack; don't check for equality, but check explicitly both s.top() and exp[i] values; just to give you an idea:

```
} else if (exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == ']') {
       if ((s.top() == '(' && exp[i] == ')') ||
           //... check for '[' matching ']' and '(' matching ')'...
```

Comment: Yes I got it i so to check what should I do